# startx not loading GUI

Tags: gui

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and am trying to startup the GUI. I installed ubuntu-desktop and xorg and rebooted but the GUI did not load. I typed `startx` and got the message:

```
    X.Org X Server 1.18.4
    Release Date: 2016-07-19
    X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
    Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-95-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
    Current Operating System: Linux tinzors 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64
    Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic root=UUID=d39864c2-d249-4a0c-b885-5c72ef360b3f ro console=tty1 root=LABEL=DOROOT notsc clocksource=kvm-clock net.ifnames=0
    Build Date: 14 September 2016  03:33:24PM
    xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
    Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
    Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Oct 12 16:50:09 2016
    (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

...but no desktop GUI appeared.. can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you create `.xinitrc`?

Comment: Hi - I don't think so.. if I create one, where should I place it and what should I put in it?

Comment: Update - I just created one, but what should I put inside it? I created one by typing `nano ~./xinitrc`

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?